# image.height and image.width not working properly

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.Drawing;  

namespace Bella
{
    class ReadDirs
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string pathA = @"W:\FirstChild\JeanShower\";
            int LengthPathA = pathA.Length;

            string editpath = @"E:\Rename\JeanShower\";

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(editpath);

            // These lines find all the Consoles 
            // Take a snapshot of the Console system.
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo file1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathA);
            IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = file1.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
             .Where(d => d.FullName.Contains(".jpg"));

            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirfile1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathA);
            IEnumerable<System.IO.DirectoryInfo> dirlist1 = dirfile1.GetDirectories("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
             .Where(d => d.FullName.Contains(".jpg"));



            Console.WriteLine("Step 2 Consoles path A");

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter afile1 = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"E:\rename\afile1.txt", false))
                foreach (var a in list1)
                {
                    afile1.WriteLine(a.FullName.Substring(LengthPathA).ToString());
                }
            Console.WriteLine("aConsole1.txt created from list1");
            int n = 0;

            String[] linesA = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\rename\afile1.txt");
            foreach (var s in linesA)
            {
                n++;
                System.Console.WriteLine(s);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("N= {0}", n);

            Console.WriteLine("Length of Path {0}", LengthPathA);
            Console.WriteLine("Path is {0}", pathA);

            string[] sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathA, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach (string file in sourceFiles)
            {
                using (Image sourceImage = Image.FromFile(file))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sourceImage.Width);
                    Console.WriteLine(sourceImage.Height);
                }
            }



            /* 
            Count lines with the changed names
            */
            int correct = 0;
            foreach (var s in linesA)
            {
                if (s.StartsWith("JeanShower"))
                {
                    correct++;
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine(s);
                string FullName = pathA + s;
                Console.WriteLine(FullName);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Named JeanShower is {0}", correct);

            correct = correct + 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Next Console number starts with, {0}", correct);

            /* Check size of each picture and adjust */
            DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Now;



            /* Changed name is */
            foreach (var s in linesA)
            {
                if (!s.StartsWith("JeanShower"))
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
                    string OldName = pathA + s;
                    Console.WriteLine("OldName is {0}", OldName);
                    string NewName = pathA + "JeanShower" + correct + ".jpg";
                    Console.WriteLine("NewName is {0}", NewName);
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    File.Copy(OldName, NewName);
                    Console.WriteLine("New Console Created {0}", NewName);
                    File.Delete(OldName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Oldname has been removed, {0}", OldName);
                    correct++;
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
                    string FullName = pathA + s;
                    Console.WriteLine(FullName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Already changed");
                    Console.WriteLine("");
                }

            }
            int count = correct - 1;
            Console.WriteLine("Number of pictures in directory is {0}", count);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Process is complete");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("HTML Code for index.html");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");

            string picturename = "JeanShower";
            string targetpathname = @"E:\Rename\JeanShower\index.html";
            string webpath = "FirstChild/JeanShower/";

            using (StreamWriter filelist1 = new StreamWriter(targetpathname, true))
            {
                int numpicture = 1;
                do
                {


                    filelist1.WriteLine("<div class=\"img" + numpicture + "\">");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"" + picturename + numpicture + ".htm" + "\"" + ">");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("<img src=" + "\"" + picturename + numpicture + ".jpg" + "\"" + " alt=" + "\"" + picturename + numpicture + "\"" + " height=\"300\"" + " width=\"300\"" + "> </a>");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("<div class=\"" + "desc" + numpicture + "\"" + ">");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("<div class=" + "\"" + "h4bnomargin" + "\"" + ">");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("<a href=\"" + "../" + webpath + picturename + numpicture + ".jpg" + "\"" + "> Download" + " </a>");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("</div>" + " <br>");
                    filelist1.WriteLine(picturename + numpicture);
                    filelist1.WriteLine("</div>");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("</div>");
                    filelist1.WriteLine("");

                    numpicture++;

                } while (numpicture <= count);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("HTML Code for JeanShower.css");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("");




            using (StreamWriter filelist2 = new StreamWriter(@"E:\Rename\JeanShower\JeanShower.css", true))
            {
                int numpictureCSS = 1;
                do
                {
                    filelist2.WriteLine("div." + "img" + numpictureCSS + " {  ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    margin: 1em;  ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    padding: 0.5em;            ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    border: 0.5em solid #0000ff;           ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    height: auto;            ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    width: auto;            ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    float: left;            ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    text-align: center;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("}             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("div." + "img" + numpictureCSS + " img {              ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    display: inline;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    margin: 0.5em;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    border: 1px solid #ffffff;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("}             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("div." + "img" + numpictureCSS + " a:hover img {             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    border:1px solid #0000ff;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("}             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("div.desc" + numpictureCSS + " {             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    text-align: center;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    font-weight: normal;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    height: auto;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    width: auto;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("    margin: 0.25em;             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("}             ");
                    filelist2.WriteLine("             ");
                    numpictureCSS++;



                } while (numpictureCSS <= count);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();

        }




    }


}
```

This program allows me to create HTML code for my web site. I want to read the height and width of each jpg file. I added .NET 4 to my resource. How do I get image.height and image.width to work for each JPG?  Once I get the picture height and width, I can finish writing the resize for each picture.  I am going to replace the height and width numbers with the proper numbers.

Comment: TL;DR; What's the exact problem? Please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I can't get the width and height of a picture to work properly with system.drawing installed.  I checked on your site for examples on using system.drawing and examples on image.height and image.width.

Comment: My point being: create a tiny program that demonstrates your problem instead of your current code. SO users are much more willing to help when you provide a clear problem with a proper piece of code.

Comment: The problem is the code snipets don't show me enough to debug the problem.  I have been looking for better examples on how to use system.drawing to get height and width of JPGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

namespace JpegTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var image = new Bitmap(@"test.jpeg", true);
                Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", image.Width);
                Console.WriteLine("Height: {0}", image.Height);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error." + "Check the path to the image file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To test: put an image named test.jpeg in your solution and set its `Copy To Output Directory` property to `Copy Always`.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I have been trying to solve this error with every method.       Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I figured it out by a fluke.  I am using VS 2013.  I went to Project - Add References and found System.Drawing in the framework and checked on it.  I really want to thank you for this example.  I changed to the path of one photo and it returned width and height.

Comment: You could [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and/or [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) my answer.